# What is the priority of javac generating $n.class files?

Tags: java, compilation, javac

Seems like javac generates $n files for anonymous inner classes but which inner class gets compiled into $1.class . Is there any priority in which javac compiles the inner class into it's $1.class files or is it random?

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    Thread secondThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Printing from second thread");

        }
    });

    Thread firstThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Printing from first thread");

        }
    });

    firstThread.start();
    secondThread.start();

}
```

I find that firstThread becomes Test$1.class(i used `javap -c` to check) so I'm guessing it's not according to which inner class is defined first. So what is the criteria for the creation?

`javap -c` outputs

```
    Compiled from "Test.java"
class main.Test$1 implements java.lang.Runnable {
  main.Test$1();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #10                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public void run();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #17                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #23                 // String Printing from first thread
       5: invokevirtual #25                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return        
}

Compiled from "Test.java"
class main.Test$2 implements java.lang.Runnable {
  main.Test$2();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #10                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public void run();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #17                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #23                 // String Printing from second thread
       5: invokevirtual #25                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return        
}
```

Above you see Test$1 containing the firstThread even though firstThread is located at a later point in the `main()` is there any reason behind this?

Comment: It isn't defined. Why do you care?

Comment: I just wanted to figure out how javac creates the $classes. What's not defined?

Comment: @MasterAwesome what EJP means, if I'm not wrong, is that the choice of which anonymous class is $1 and which one is $2 is an implementation detail of the compiler that is not specified anywhere, and that you shouldn't care about: the class is anonymous, so it doesn't have a name, so whether its corresponding class file is $1 or $2 shouldn't matter.